# MonoTouch.Dialog: ContentSizeForViewInPopover changes in Date

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a Reflection-created dialog that looks like below. When the date is clicked, the popover changes shape and renders the datepicker squished, see below too.

My Class is below for reference.

[image]

[image]

```
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class EventEntity
{


    [Section("Date of Measurement", "")]
    [Indexed]
    [Date]
    public DateTime Date ;


    [Section("Measurement Details", "")]
    [Caption("Height")]
    [Entry(Placeholder= "Centimeters",KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad)]
    public string HeightCM ;


    [Caption("Weight")]
    [Entry(Placeholder= "Kilograms",KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad)]
    public string WeightKG ;


    [Caption("Head Circumference")]
    [Entry(Placeholder = "Centimeters", KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad)]
    public string HeadCircumferenceCM;


    [Skip]
    public int ChildFK ;

    [Skip]
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int PK;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide me with a self-contained test case, I could look into debugging that.   I never really used MonoTouch.Dialog in the iPad ;-)